# fread gets more chars than i ask in c while working with binary file

Tags: c, string, binaryfiles, fread

i'm a beginner in C and in my internship i have to work with a binary file and i must read the information in a binary file, one information at a time,

```
int main()
{
FILE *ptr=fopen("C:\\Users\\Workstation\\Desktop\\TEST.MAILO","rb");

char header[65];
char CRLF[3];
char first40[41];
char rio[33];
char date_capture[9];


if (ptr==NULL){
    printf("Erreur");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

fread(header, sizeof(char), 64, ptr);
fread(CRLF, sizeof(char), 2, ptr);
fread(first40,sizeof(char),40,ptr);
fread(rio,sizeof(char),32,ptr);
fread(date_capture,sizeof(char),8,ptr);

printf("%s%s",header,CRLF);
printf("%s|||%s|||",first40,rio);
printf("%s||",date_capture);

return 0;
}
```

the problem is that in the last variable "date_capture" i ask for 8chars for the date but it gets more than 8

**EIMG05050120170609007MADIMC0500014
0310000032050810011010358897200120007780|||007MAD00901020170609000109259941|||20170608■007MAD00901020170609000109259941||**

it is supposed to print only 20170608 without the rest **■007MAD00901020170609000109259941||** 
please help me i looked everywhere i haven't found any problem like this. THANK YOU

Comment: After the ``fread(date_capture,sizeof(char),8,ptr);`` add ``date_capture[8+1] = '\0';``

Comment: `fread()` doesn't know anything about the nature of the argument passed to it, it treats it as `void *` . All that it knows is to read some bytes specified from your file and write them to the buffer.

Comment: so, obviously the assumption that it'll append a null character to your char array is unfortunately wrong. You should check its documentation as well.

Comment: That is a binary file?

Comment: Formatting/indentation:(

Comment: You must check the result returned by all system calls, eg. fread().

Comment: You cannot safely/sanely use printf("%s...) on data read from a 'binary' file, (except that subset of files that are guaranteed to hold no embedded NULs).

Comment: Append a _null character_ or or limit printing width `printf("%.64s%.2s",header,CRLF);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fread` will not null terminate the buffer passed to it, you are seeing extra characters as the data in `date_capture` is not null terminated, you should call `memset` to set `date_capture` to all zeros prior to passing it to fread

Comment: fread docs: 'The total number of elements successfully read is returned', so it's easy to add a NUL at the correct place to terminate a TEXT string in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not getting more than 8 bytes from the file. `fread` does not add any string terminator to your buffer. Try to add it yourself or initialize your buffers all to 0.

Comment: fread docs: 'The total number of elements successfully read is returned', so it's easy to add a NUL at the correct place to terminate a TEXT string in the buffer.